# Why does my Xcode archive version number differ from the build version number?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've been working on this React-Native project for many years and with this latest version (305) the build number in the archive is showing as 5, not 305.  I'm not sure what I changed. See the general tab setting here in the attached image. Why does this not match?

Image top half: info.plist
Image bottom half: archive window

[image: xcode example image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your version value is incorrect. You are to supply a *version string*, which is a string (not a number) of the form:

```
MAJOR.MINOR
```

or

```
MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH
```

These are not decimals. The major, minor, and patch values are all (string representations of) *integers*. Thus, for example, "1.34" is much bigger, not smaller, than "1.4" — because 34 is much bigger than 4.

If you were numbering these versions correct, you would never in a million years have gotten to a major version as big as 305.

When you submit a new version to TestFlight, you increment the *other* number, the Build, which *is* an integer. You typically increment the Version in some way only when you release a new version in the app store.

Comment: Are you saying in the version field it needs to be "305" instead of 305? When I initially setup version 1 I had it as 0.0.1, but xcode/app store cut it off and made it just: 1.

Comment: I am not saying that. But note that `0.0.1` isn't legal either. MAJOR can be 0 but MINOR cannot. Instead of flailing around you should learn what a version string is. :)

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I'll improve on that. That's one reason I'm here, is to learn. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the version to 306 and made another archive and the number was correct. Changed it back to 305 and archived, and it was correct.  I guess this was a simple glitch.
[image]

Comment: Note however that "305" is an improper version. You are versioning your builds incorrectly. The heat death of the universe will arrive before any real software reaches version 305.

Comment: Matt:  It's actually version 3.05, but the way xcode and the app store deal with decimals made it turn into 305 instead of 3.05.... if that makes any sense.

Comment: 3.05 is wrong too. These are not decimals! You are to supply a _version string_.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I'll look at that.